# ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Tags: spring-boot, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

I'm working in e-commerce application back end with spring, front end with angular. When I run the app with `ng serve` command the following error appears :

```html
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\ecommerce-project\03-frontend\angular-ecommerc>ng serve

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 20.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 268 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 1.69 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.33 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-06-16T13:43:02.010Z - Hash: c4671c1e2b0f67c7381a - Time: 16027ms

ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\ecommerce-project\03-frontend\angular-ecommerc\node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-free\css\all.min.css' in 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\ecommerce-project\03-frontend\angular-ecommerc'
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
```

Comment: did you install @fortawesome?

Comment: yes it appear under node_modules

Comment: problem resolved, the @fortawesome was not correctly installed